# Find Highest Sum below/equals given Limit

Tags: javascript

I've got the following function:

```js
var object = [12,23,14,35,24];
//debugger;
function f(objects, sum){
  var curSum = objects[0];
  var maxSum = 0;
  var start = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < objects.length; i++) {
    while(curSum > sum && start < i){
      curSum -= objects[start];
      start++
    }
    maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, curSum);
    curSum += objects[i];
    if(curSum <= sum){
      maxSum = Math.max(curSum, maxSum);
    }
  }
  return maxSum;
}

console.log(f(object,50));
```

I'd expect the highest possible sum to be 50, due to elements `12,14,24`

However, I can only manage to get to 49. What am I missing here?

Comment: Highest sum from any order of items, or consecutive?

Comment: ANY order, I'm quite new to this language. I only manage to find consecutive @DominicTobias

Comment: `Find Highest Sum below given Limit`   Erm,.. 50 is not below 50, but 49 is..

Comment: @Keith I mean below/equals. Like my conditions should do it. Updated title

Comment: It's look like a knapsack problem

Comment: Your current code only ever traverses from left to right,  so the the 49 = 12,23,14, adding the next number will of course be more than 49..  Like @nutboltu pointed out maybe the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem will help.  There is pseudo code in there to try.

Comment: this is causing me headaches...

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/

Comment: The highest possible sum of an indetermined count of element is the sum of all those elements. The highest possible sum should be `12 + 23 + 14 + 35 + 24 = 108`. What are you trying to do, @Hendrik Breezy?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach by iterating the array and check if the temporary array has the right sum and check against the result for eiter replaceinf smaller sums or push to same sum parts.

```js
function combine(array, sum) {
    function fork(i, p) {
        var s = p.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
            l = (result[0] || []).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

        if (i === array.length) {
            if (s <= sum) {
                if (l < s) {
                    result = [p];
                }
                if (l === s) {
                    result.push(p);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        fork(i + 1, p.concat(array[i]));
        fork(i + 1, p);
    }
    var result = [];
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(combine([12, 23, 14, 35, 24], 50));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```